# How can I attach an analog to digital converter to a guitar

Tags: operational-amplifier, preamp, guitar-amplifier

I want to modify an electric guitar to add an ADC and microcontroller to drive some LEDs for fancy effects that follow music.

Since typical output levels of pickups are about 100mV, I was thinking of adding an op-amp circuit in parallel to the output of the guitar, independent of the any other amps the user may connect.

Since the power generated by the pickups is so low, I am not sure of they can drive both the op-amp and the other amplifiers? Do I have to provide pre-amplification to the guitar output so it can still be used as an instrument?

EDIT: I am not trying to power up form string vibrations. I foresee battery, I am only concerned about the loading of the pickups, "losing" the signal they create in the process. I want it to be playable as usual.

Comment: If you're worried about loading the pickup up use a high impedance buffer (unity gain) stage followed by your amplifier stage. There are lots of dual op amps out there.

Comment: You are wondering if you can power the op amp via the string vibrations? The op amps need a clean *DC* power source. Converting the pickup output to a signal that can power op amps would be interesting, but I doubt practical if even possible.

Comment: You may have better success using an active pickup or an add-on preamp stage.  Active pickups have built-in preamps, as they use much weaker magnets and smaller coils to reduce noise.  Only instead of tying the active pickup output to the guitar's output jack, you run it into your ADC.  Add-on preamp, same thing, only it's designed to take the input from a passive pickup and amplify it.  Both run on 9V, sometimes 18V.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisM. indeed it looks like technically the best solution but for now I'm trying to keep things as cheap as possible, so maybe something like LM358 double op-amp and a couple AA batteries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output impedance of a guitar is in the order of 10k ohms. If your op amp circuit has an input impedance of say 100k ohms, there will be no significant loading of the guitar output nor any affect on downstream amps or effects boxes.

In order to keep the input impedance of your added circuit as high as possible, pick off the signal with a unity gain buffer and then follow that with a gain stage as needed to match your uP ADC input. An LM358 would be a suitable op amp, for example.

Do take care to keep your op amp input leads short to avoid stray pickup due to the high input impedance.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to drive your LED's without a separate power source, so I would recommend you use a microcontroller board with a battery.  A small Arduino board would have an on-board ADC and provide the ability to directly drive a small number of LEDs.  I don't use them myself, but I would recommend you use the Arduino because of the number of sample programs and support documentation out there.  There will be an example where someone has done something very similar to what you are attempting.

Comment: I am definitely going to put some battery of course. My concern is, will my setup allow the player to play it as usual, if I attach it in parallel.

Comment: Good question.  If you use a single channel and leave the ADC on, I don't think you will be able to tell any difference.  If you switch between ADC channels you might pick up the capacitive discharge.